# Obfuscated way of accessing a character in string

Tags: c++, obfuscation

I found today interesting piece of code:

```
auto ch = (double(), (float(), int()))["\t\a\r\n\0"]["abcdefghij"];
```

which works same as:

```
char str[] = "abcdefghij";
char ch = str['\t'];
```

Why is it even possible? Especially why is the compiler picking first char from string and using it as subscript instead of throwing error?

Comment: gcc gives three warnings: two unused-values and one char-subscript.

Comment: But none of those warnings are particularly critical, they're just things that programmers would normally not want to do... unless of course they were intentionally obfuscating their code. And since `\t` is ASCII value 11, and the string it's indexing into is exactly 11 characters long (including nul-terminator), this code is perfectly well-defined and well-behaved, if ridiculous.

Comment: -1 I see nothing interesting here.

Comment: @Tyler McHenry: FWIW, the `\t` is ASCII TAB, decimal 9, hex 9, but octal 11.  Is the code still well defined?

Comment: Whoops, looked in the wrong column on my ASCII chart -- yes, it's decimal 9. It is still well-defined (although it wouldn't actually have been if it were 11.. I made a mistake there too! Need more coffee.)

Comment: @Stephane: Downvoting because you don't find the problem interesting? Seems pretty pointless. The fact that both answers delve into the standards and use rewrites to make the issue more readable makes me think this is quite an interesting problem. If it isn't interesting to you because you understand it, why not answer instead of downvoting? I see no other reason to downvote, the post follows the rules and is a programming related question. (Oh, and +1 to offset the -1!)

Comment: It is more than not interresting for me. Indeed I don't like the ways to write code that is not understandable. The obvious being the ( double(), float(), int() )... I mean you could put all lot of futile meaningless things this way using the comma.

Comment: @Stephane: So you're complaining about obfuscated code in topic, which is about obfuscation. That one is even more interesting. So are you going to downvote everyone who dares to touch the topic which scares you? And it seems obfuscation does. Noone is encouraging anyone to use it, it was just a question ...

Comment: If it implies obfuscating using the comma operator as in this current case, yes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll explain as rewrite:

```
auto ch = (double(), (float(), int()))["\t\a\r\n\0"]["abcdefghij"];
```

is equivalent to (just evaluate all the `double, float, int` temporaries with comma operator)

```
auto ch = (0["\t\a\r\n\0"])["abcdefghij"];
```

Now the standard says that:

```
x[y] == *(x + y)
```

No matter which one is a pointer. so you get:

```
0["\t\a\r\n\0"] == "\t\a\r\n\0"[0] == '\t';
```

Answer (score 12):

So first of all, all that `double` and `float` stuff is pure misdirection. The comma operator's return value is its right-side argument, so `(double(), (float(), int()))` boils down to just `int()`, although it creates and discards a `double` and a `float` value along the way. So consider:

```
 auto ch = int()["\t\a\r\n\0"]["abcdefghij"];
```

The first part of this that will be evaluated is

```
 int()["\t\a\r\n\0"]
```

Now, recognize that `int()` default-constructs an integer, which gives it the value `0`. So the statement is equivalent to:

```
 0["\t\a\r\n\0"]
```

It's a fairly well known trick in C and C++ that `a[b]` and `b[a]` are equivalent, since the subscript operator is defined as `a[b] === *(a + b)` and addition is commutative. So this is really the same as:

```
 "\t\a\r\n\0"[0]
```

which is of course equal to `'\t'`. Now the full piece of code is:

```
 auto ch = '\t'["abcdefghij"];
```

which for the same reason is equivalent to:

```
 auto ch = "abcdefghij"['\t'];
```

Which of course could also be written as

```
char str[] = "abcdefghij";
char ch = str['\t'];
```

If you gave the "abcdefghij" string a name and forwent the use of the C++0x `auto` keyword when declaring `ch`.

Finally, note that `\t` is equal to 9 since the tab character has ASCII value 9, so `str['\t']` is the same as `str[9]`. `str` consists of 10 characters followed by a NUL character terminator (`\0`), which is implicitly added to the string literal that it was initialized with.

So in both cases the final value of `ch` is `'j'`.

Comment: Great explanation, but `(int)'\t' == 9`, not 11.

Comment: And if it *were* 11, it would be undefined, because index 11 would be one character *beyond* the null terminator.  Since C++ uses zero-based indexing, the 11th element is accessed with index 10.